# Is multithreaded FFTW deterministic

Tags: multithreading, fftw, deterministic

I am getting slightly different results between runs in my program. It uses multi-threaded FFTW planned with `FFTW_ESTIMATE` flag. Is multi-threaded FFTW deterministic:

1. For fixed number of threads?
2. Between different numbers of threads used at different runs?

FFTW faq says, that `FFTW_ESTIMATE` flag results in same algorithm used between runs, but it does not explicitly say that it is deterministic in multi-threaded case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fftw documentation:

http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Thread-safety.html#Thread-safety

stipulates that only `fftw_execute` is reentrant. So it's hard to say without more info about your usage. Also:

"If you are configured FFTW with the --enable-debug or --enable-debug-malloc flags (see Installation on Unix), then fftw_execute is not thread-safe. These flags are not documented because they are intended only for developing and debugging FFTW, but if you must use --enable-debug then you should also specifically pass --disable-debug-malloc for fftw_execute to be thread-safe."

Comment: My program itself is not multi-threaded. I am using multi-threaded FFTW (by calling `fftwf_plan_with_nthreads` function before creating a plan).

Comment: Have you tried comparing the results from plain plan vs plan with nthreads setting the number of threads to 1?

Comment: Yes, getting same answer. I found a bug in my code. Now I am always getting same results. Still would like to confirm that multi-threaded FFTW is deterministic...

Comment: As long as you did not compile with --enable-debug or --enable-debug-malloc (see my answer) you should be fine.